# Check and display how many times a letter appears (A,B,C etc..) PHP

Tags: php, count, instances

I am trying to find the occurences of letters in a while().. but it's not quite working out for me right now... This is the code I have right now:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM shops ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// Previous or first letter
$first = "";
// Current letter
$current = "";
$c_instances = 0;
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

    $current = strtoupper(substr($obj->name,0,1));

    if(empty($first)){
        $first = strtoupper(substr($obj->name,0,1));
    }

    if($current != $first){
        ?>
            <a href=""><li><?=$first;?> <span><?=$c_instances;?></span></li></a>
        <?
        $first = strtoupper(substr($obj->name,0,1));
        $c_instances = 0;
    }
    $c_instances++;

}
```

This does work sort of, but when it comes to the last letter, it doesn't show it. As it is now right now, it ranges from A-H, but it only shows from A to F, not the two last shops starting with "H". I sort of know what is causing it, but my brain can't get around it right now.. I believe it's being caused because it uses $first instead of $current, so it echo's out the one before.. Let me know if you have an idea to solve this.. thanks

[image]

Comment: Surely you could do this calculation in the SQL

Comment: You just have to echo this line(one more time) outside of your `while` loop, `<a href=""><li><?=$first;?> <span><?=$c_instances;?></span></li></a>`

Answer (score 1):

You could get the SQL to do all the work for you if you wanted

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,1,1) as First, count(name)
from shops
GROUP BY First
ORDER BY First;
```